# SQL Query : available products from component list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to build a report named "Available products"
The goal is to have a list of products ready to be made based on the components available in the Database.
So the SQL query would ignore a product when one of its components is unavailable.

For example :

Component List :

```
ID1 - Wood Leg - 40

ID2 - Table Top grey - 5

ID3 - Table Top Black - 3

ID4 - Table Top yellow - 0
```

By order of component ID, Available products should be :

```
Grey Table - 5

Black Table - 3
```

Knowing that we can't make a Yellow table because one component is missing.

Thanks

Comment: What would be the result if there were only 30 wood legs?

Comment: The result would be 
4 grey tables and 2 black tables 
order by component ID

Comment: 30 legs are enough for 7 tables. (Assuming each table has 4 legs.) However, your tables have no component ID from what I can see.

Comment: My mistake, 
5 grey tables 
2 black tables 
Total 7 tables 
I'm going to edit the question and add component ID

Comment: @Zameta Can you please give your table schema?

Comment: <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rnSsTOr-CmZhkjA1FC9m57vtfPDxS1MK/view?usp=sharing">